# export json data to csv from mongodb

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, csv

I am having the problem with missing field name in python script when exported data to csv from mongodb. type field name exists in first record, but it does not appear in the rest of records. how to write python script to give null value for type field if it does not exist.

the sample of Mongodb collection:

```
"stages": [
    {
        "interview": false,
        "hmNotification": false,
        "hmStage": false,
        "type": "new",
        "isEditable": false,
        "order": 0,
        "name": {
            "en": "New"
        },
        "stageId": "51d1a2f4c0d9887b214f3694"
    },
    {
        "interview": false,
        "hmNotification": true,
        "isEditable": true,
        "order": 1,
        "hmStage": true,
        "name": {
            "en": "Pre-Screen"
        },
        "stageId": "51f0078d7297363f62059699"
    },
    {
        "interview": false,
        "hmNotification": false,
        "hmStage": false,
        "isEditable": true,
        "order": 2,
        "name": {
            "en": "Phone Screen"
        },
        "stageId": "51d1a326c0d9887721778eae"
    }]
```

the sample of Python script:

```
import csv
cursor = db.workflows.find( {}, {'_id': 1, 'stages.interview': 1, 'stages.hmNotification': 1, 'stages.hmStage': 1, 'stages.type':1, 'stages.isEditable':1, 'stages.order':1,   
'stages.name':1, 'stages.stageId':1 })
flattened_records = []
for stages_record in cursor:
    stages_record_id = stages_record['_id']
    for stage_record in stages_record['stages']:
        flattened_record = {
            '_id': stages_record_id,
            'stages.interview': stage_record['interview'],
            'stages.hmNotification': stage_record['hmNotification'],
            'stages.hmStage': stage_record['hmStage'],
            'stages.type': stage_record['type'],  
            'stages.isEditable': stage_record['isEditable'],
            'stages.order': stage_record['order'],
            'stages.name': stage_record['name'],
            'stages.stageId': stage_record['stageId']}                   
        flattened_records.append(flattened_record)
```

when run the python script, it shows keyerror:"type". please help me how to add the missing field name in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're trying to fetch values that might not exist in a Python dictionary, you can use the [`.get()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm) method of the [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) class.

For instance, let's say you have a dictionary like this:

```
my_dict = {'a': 1, 
           'b': 2,
           'c': 3}
```

You can use the `get` method to get one of the keys that exist:

```
>>> print(my_dict.get('a'))
1
```

But if you try to get a key that doesn't exist (such as `does_not_exist`), you will get `None` by default:

```
>>> print(my_dict.get("does_not_exist"))
None
```

As mentioned in the documentation, you can also provide a *default* value that will be returned when the key doesn't exist:

```
>>> print(my_dict.get("does_not_exist", "default_value"))
default_value
```

But this default value won't be used if the key does exist in the dictionary (if the key does exist, you'll get its value):

```
>>> print(my_dict.get("a", "default_value"))
1
```

Knowing that, when you build your *flattened_record* you can do:

```
'stages.hmStage': stage_record['hmStage'],
'stages.type': stage_record.get('type', ""),  
'stages.isEditable': stage_record['isEditable'],
```

So if the `stage_record` dictionary doesn't contain a key `type`, `get('type')` will return an empty string.

You can also try with just:

```
'stages.hmStage': stage_record['hmStage'],
'stages.type': stage_record.get('type'),  
'stages.isEditable': stage_record['isEditable'],
```

and then `stage_record.get('type')` will return `None` when that `stage_record` doesn't contain a `type` key.

Or you could make the default `"UNKNOWN"`

```
'stages.type': stage_record.get('type', "UNKNOWN"),
```

Comment: It worked very well when added " stages.typ':stage_record.get('type') in the python script . the value of type appears in CSV file. Thanks so much.

Comment: thanks for your help. how do I remove u letter , brackets and the name of sub fields in Python? thanks.